# html iframe embed link doesn't work

Tags: html, video, iframe, embed, src

They gave me a really long video link to embed in html:

http://up.anv.bz/latest/anvload.html?key=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

It shows a video if i copy it into the browser, but not in my iframe:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
            src="http://up.anv.bz/latest/anvload.html?key=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">
</iframe>
```

If I use a youtube embed link instead it works fine, so I know my code is good.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I checked your code it's working in my system, Are you getting any error?

Comment: Ya it says Mixed Content: The page at 'https://testingsite.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://up.anv.bz/latest/anvload.html?key=...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: So I either have to get an https embed link or change that one page to http? Not sure if I can or want to do the second one

Comment: Can you share the original link to the video. I mean without embedded. Is it available on youtube or another site?

Comment: ya it's on a news site: http://wavy.com/2017/11/21/home-repairs-made-easy/